# Digitally sign multiple PDF files with an E-ID in a specified folder

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itext, bouncycastle

Note: I have heavily edited most of my post as I have advanced a bit further now

I am currently working on a small project: the general idea is that the user selects a folder, inserts his E-ID and all PDF files in that folder are modified with his digital signature and an image to represent this when printed.
I am currently using the iTextSharp framework to accomplish this. But because I have to convert the source to VB.NET, I have hit a full stop.

The following code accomplishes its task of adding a digital signature to a PDF document, however. It only does so with the test-certificate I have created with Visual Studio. Anything else and the PDF just isn't created, I have checked with breakpoints and myPkcs12Store does not get filled with anything: I cannot retrieve the personal key from the eID.

```
   Private Sub Test()
    Dim myKeyStore As New X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser)
    myKeyStore.Open(OpenFlags.[ReadOnly])
    Dim myCertificateCollection As X509Certificate2Collection = myKeyStore.Certificates
    Dim myCertificate As X509Certificate2 = Nothing
    Dim selectedCertificates As X509Certificate2Collection = X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(myCertificateCollection, "Certificaten", "Select een certificaat om te tekenen", X509SelectionFlag.SingleSelection)

    If selectedCertificates.Count > 0 Then
        Dim certificatesEnumerator As X509Certificate2Enumerator = selectedCertificates.GetEnumerator()
        certificatesEnumerator.MoveNext()
        myCertificate = certificatesEnumerator.Current
    End If
    myKeyStore.Close()

    'Settings'
    Dim source = "source.pdf"
    Dim result = "result.pdf"
    Dim reason = "test"
    Dim Location = "locatie"


    Dim myPkcs12Store As New Pkcs12Store()
    Using memorystreamPfx As New System.IO.MemoryStream(myCertificate.Export(X509ContentType.Pkcs12))
        myPkcs12Store.Load(memorystreamPfx, "")
    End Using


    For Each strAlias As String In myPkcs12Store.Aliases
        If myPkcs12Store.IsKeyEntry(strAlias) Then
            Dim pk = myPkcs12Store.GetKey(strAlias).Key

            Using myPdfReader As New PdfReader(source)
                Using myFileStream As New FileStream(result, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
                    Using myPdfStamper As PdfStamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(myPdfReader, myFileStream, "0")
                        Dim myPdfDocument As New Document(myPdfReader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1))

                        'Define the digital signature appearance'
                        Dim myPdfSignatureAppearance As PdfSignatureAppearance = myPdfStamper.SignatureAppearance
                        myPdfSignatureAppearance.CertificationLevel = PdfSignatureAppearance.CERTIFIED_NO_CHANGES_ALLOWED
                        myPdfSignatureAppearance.Image = Image.GetInstance("Images/poro1_by_justduet-d63wx6c.png")
                        myPdfSignatureAppearance.Reason = reason
                        myPdfSignatureAppearance.Location = Location
                        myPdfSignatureAppearance.SetVisibleSignature(New iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(myPdfDocument.PageSize.Width - 120, 36, myPdfDocument.PageSize.Width - 36, 96), myPdfReader.NumberOfPages, "Digital Signature")

                        'Attach digital signature to PDF document'
                        Dim myExternalSignature As IExternalSignature = New PrivateKeySignature(pk, "SHA-256")
                        MakeSignature.SignDetached(myPdfSignatureAppearance, myExternalSignature, {(myPkcs12Store.GetCertificate(strAlias).Certificate)}, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, 0, CryptoStandard.CMS)
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
        End If
    Next
```

Any help would be appreciated! Further questions please ask

bdebaere

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for an answer to this:

```
Dim myX509Store As New X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser)
    myX509Store.Open(OpenFlags.[ReadOnly])
    'Dim myCertificateCollection As X509Certificate2Collection = myX509Store.Certificates
    Dim myCertificateChain As IList(Of X509Certificate) = New List(Of X509Certificate)()
    Dim myCertificate As X509Certificate2 = Nothing
    Dim myCertificateCollection As X509Certificate2Collection = X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(myX509Store.Certificates, "Certificaten", "Select een certificaat om te tekenen", X509SelectionFlag.SingleSelection)

    If myCertificateCollection.Count > 0 Then
        Dim certificatesEnumerator As X509Certificate2Enumerator = myCertificateCollection.GetEnumerator()
        certificatesEnumerator.MoveNext()
        myCertificate = certificatesEnumerator.Current
        'myCertificate = selectedCertificates(0)

        Dim myX509Chain As New X509Chain()
        myX509Chain.Build(myCertificate)

        For Each myChainElement As X509ChainElement In myX509Chain.ChainElements
            myCertificateChain.Add(DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(myChainElement.Certificate))
        Next
    End If
    myX509Store.Close()

    Dim ocspClient As IOcspClient = New OcspClientBouncyCastle()
    Dim tsaClient As ITSAClient = Nothing
    For intI As Integer = 0 To myCertificateChain.Count - 1
        Dim cert As X509Certificate = myCertificateChain(intI)
        Dim tsaUrl As String = CertificateUtil.GetTSAURL(cert)

        If tsaUrl IsNot Nothing Then
            tsaClient = New TSAClientBouncyCastle(tsaUrl)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    Dim crlList As IList(Of ICrlClient) = New List(Of ICrlClient)()
    crlList.Add(New CrlClientOnline(myCertificateChain))





    'Settings
    Dim source = "source.pdf"
    Dim result = "result.pdf"
    Dim reason = "test"
    Dim Location = "locatie"
    Using myPdfReader As New PdfReader(source)
        Using myFileStream As New FileStream(result, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
            Using myPdfStamper As PdfStamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(myPdfReader, myFileStream, "0"c)
                Dim myPdfDocument As New Document(myPdfReader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1))


                'Define the digital signature appearance
                Dim myPdfSignatureAppearance As PdfSignatureAppearance = myPdfStamper.SignatureAppearance
                myPdfSignatureAppearance.CertificationLevel = PdfSignatureAppearance.CERTIFIED_NO_CHANGES_ALLOWED
                'myPdfSignatureAppearance.Image = Image.GetInstance("Images/poro1_by_justduet-d63wx6c.png")
                myPdfSignatureAppearance.Reason = reason
                myPdfSignatureAppearance.Location = Location
                myPdfSignatureAppearance.SetVisibleSignature(New iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(myPdfDocument.PageSize.Width - 120, 36, myPdfDocument.PageSize.Width - 36, 96), myPdfReader.NumberOfPages, "Digital Signature")


                Dim pks As IExternalSignature = New X509Certificate2Signature(myCertificate, DigestAlgorithms.SHA1)

                'Attach digital signature to PDF document
                'Dim myExternalSignature As IExternalSignature = New PrivateKeySignature(pk, "SHA-256")
                MakeSignature.SignDetached(myPdfSignatureAppearance, pks, myCertificateChain, crlList, ocspClient, tsaClient, 0, CryptoStandard.CMS)
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
```

The only problem is if you are using eID for every PDF you have to enter your PIN.

bdebaere